A discrete optimization problem
We have $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{C} ^{N\times K},\mathbf{A}=\left[ \begin{matrix}
 a_{1,1}&  …&  a_{1,K}\\
 …&  a_{i,j}&  …\\
 a_{N,1}&  …&  a_{N,K}\\
\end{matrix} \right] ,|a_{i,j}|>0$,
$\mathbf{B}=\mathrm{diag}\left( e^{j\phi _1},e^{j\phi _2},…,e^{j\phi _K} \right) \in \mathbb{C} ^{K\times K},\phi _k\in \left\{ \alpha _1,\alpha _2,…,\alpha _L \right\}$, $\alpha _l\in \left[ 0,2\pi \right),N>K$, $K>L$. In fact, the same elements will exist on the diagonal in $\mathbf{B}$. We assume that there are $L(L<K)$ distinct elements on the diagonal of $\mathbf{B}$.
Then, $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{AB}=\left[ \mathbf{c}_1,\mathbf{c}_2,…,\mathbf{c}_N \right] ^H\in \mathbb{C} ^{N\times K},\mathbf{e}=\left[ 1,1,…,1 \right] ^T\in \mathbb{R} ^{K\times 1}$.
I want to solve the following problem by optimizing both $\alpha_l$ and $\phi_k$ when given $\mathbf{A},N,K$, and $L$:
$
\underset{\alpha _l,\phi _k}{\max}\,\,\sum_{n=1}^N{|\mathbf{c}_{n}^{H}\mathbf{e}|}
\\
\,\,         \mathrm{s}.\mathrm{t}.\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{AB}.$
I'm looking for a good way/algorithm to optimize both $\alpha_l$ and $\phi_k$ so that I can get a good $\mathbf{B}$. This is actually a discrete optimization problem, but I'm at a complete loss as to where to start, and would appreciate some help. The difficulty of the problem is that the choice of $\phi_k$ is discrete, but the optimisation of $\alpha_l$ is continuous.

Do you expect the solution to be bounded? Is there some motivation, or natural interpretation for this optimization problem? Also, it is unclear with your formatting, are you minimizing on $\phi$ and maximizing on $\alpha$?

@caduk I wish I had an algorithm to find a good $\mathbf{B}$, I can only think of doing it with an exhaustive list at the moment. The problem in actuality is a hardware architecture connectivity approach, but of course the actual problem is far from concise, I'm thinking of getting some insights. Besides, I edited it and I mean maximizing on both $\alpha$ and $\phi$.
